# Find the number of the digits 5?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

## I couldn't solve the problem:

> "Consider two four-digit numbers, where the second is obtained from the first by writing it in the reverse order. Find the maximum number of digits 5 in the number, which is the absolute value of the difference of those two numbers."
>
> Please help!

Comment: You can't solve it, but what have you tried?

Comment: I have no idea what to try. The problem is too difficult for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$7622$ and $2267$ give difference $5355$ , hence $3$ fives are possible. Since the difference must be disivible by $9$ , $4$ fives are impossible.

Hence the answer is $3$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Peter!